# Best way to rotate logs by size and date

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have an application which uses logback. The problem is that I want to rotate by size and date (until now ok), but I want to put a limit on the total size(this is the problem).

i.e If I delete files every 10 days, I have too much logs in the disk, so I want to have a rule to keep lets say 10 log files maximum. Following this thought I will have 10 files * maxsize(of each file) = total size of logs in disk. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The rolling policies of logback have a property called maxHistory: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy

With it you can configure how many rolled files to keep, any older files will be deleted by logback upon rolling the latest log file.

As you already said, estimate the maximum size of a day's logfile and divide your available space by it to have an idea about how many files to keep at most.

Comment: The problem is that I want to have logs for 14 days, but if the size of the total files are above lets say 1gb I want to rotate and delete the oldest file.

Comment: There is no standard mechanism in logback to achieve that. You would have to write your own appender.